# Как вернуть значение переменной из потока asyncTask android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

У меня есть класс потока asyncTask

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String arr;
String res;

public RequestTask(String arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    res = "10";
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

}

Запускаю в методе onClick некоторой активности

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            setTrueFalse();

            RequestTask requestTask = new RequestTask("2");
            requestTask.execute();
            // String s = ...
        }
```

Как я могу получить значение переменной res, класса AsyncTask в переменную s.
AsyncTask не внутренний и не анонимный класс.

Comment: если переменная нужна именно снаружи, то запишите результат в статическую переменную

Comment: Спасибо, так я и сделал!

Answer (score 1):

*А вы ребята как ни садитесь...*

`AsyncTask` предполагает, что неизвестно когда будет завершена его работа, соответственно если вы запишете `res` в глобальную переменную и попробуете его взять в другом месте то не зная завершен поток или нет вы получите просто `null` (в лучшем случае). Выхода 2:

1. Организовать слушатель, который известит об окончании работы `AsyncTask` и далее по его окончании что-то сделать
2. Применить `res` в самом `AsyncTask` уже после завершения (идеальное место `onPostExecute()`

Приблизительная схема реализации второго способа в предположении, что значение `res` надо вывести в `TextView` (как пример):

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String arr;
String res;
TextView tv;

public RequestTask(String arr, TextView tv) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.tv=tv;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    res = "10";
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    tv.setText(res);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
}


// вызов
RequestTask requestTask = new RequestTask("2", myTextView);
requestTask.execute();
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я обошелся while(res == null) {}. В моем случае просто не подходит вариант с использованием UI

Comment: Гениальное решение - блокировать UI тред бесконечным циклом, с чем вас и поздравляю :)

Comment: Почему же бесконечным? Рано или поздно значение переменной установится, по идее. Да, приложение из за этого будет неопитимизировано, но все же

Comment: Такая блокировка противоречит самой идее асинхронности: то есть длинный процесс выводим в асинхрон, а сами крутимся в основном потоке ожидая завершения асинхрона. Не находите, что это по меньшей мере странно, если не сказать глупо. Зачем тогда вообще нужен асинхрон - получайте данные в основном потоке :)

Comment: Вы не понимаете идеологию *event-driven* программирования, пытаетесь обычное однопоточное программирование применить к асинхрону... Ну в общем я на этом пожалуй что все.

Comment: Я хоть и не понимаю своей ошибки, все таки ее признаю. Завтра почитаю об асинхроне поболее